# How to detect if the product with the same name already exist in opencart 1.5.2.1

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I wonna know if it is possible and if there is any extension for detecting the products duplicate names in OpenCart???

For Example... 
When i am inserting a product name then there should be a script which detects through AJAX etc... that this name already exist in the DB or not...

Is there any existing extension which you can recommend me? ? ?

Comment: Sounds like you know how it should work, give it a try then post back any problems you run into. You can use this free extension as a starting point/guide: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=65

Comment: Definitely possible, and pretty straight forward. You got the process already. Don't know about existing extensions though. Either modify addProduct() and editProduct() functions in admin/model/catalog/product.php to check whether Product name already exist, or do the AJAX call from the tpl to check values as you type. You can add a custom method to your admin/controller/catalog/product.php then call it from tpl with ajax like ./index.php?route=catalog/product/my_function

Comment: Maybe better to edit validateForm() function in admin/controller/catalog/product.php to check if name already exists. Then add a custom error message, no need for AJAX.